# Advanced rectangles collision in processing

Tags: math, processing

Coded in procesing (processing.org):
I want to know when the mouse or another shape collides with a rectangle,
this is very easy but I have one problem: I want it to work when the rectangle is rotated (example: rotate(radians(90))).

Comment: Change the coordinates to a coordinate frame attached to a corner of one rectangle. You can google and implement coordinate transformation pretty trivially in whatever language (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I've never used processing, but I could try and figure it out if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Kevin and Asad's contributions are useful.

In terms of using the 2D renderer, you need to roll your own functionality for that. For this you should be familiar with a few bits and bobs of linear algebra (vector and matrices mainly and just a few operations anyway).

I am going to assume you're already familiar with 2D transformations (using `pushMatrix()/popMatrix()` along with `translate(),rotate(),scale()`) if not, I warmly recommend the [2D Transformations Processing tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/)

I am going to explain some of the concepts only briefly (as it's a big topic on it's own).

If you used `translate()/rotate()/scale()` before, it's all been matrix operations handled for you behind the scenes. In 2D, a transformation can be stored in a 3x3 matrix like so:

```
X Y T
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

The rotation and scale are stored in the 1st and 2nd column (2 values each) while translation is stored in the last column. In theory you could have a 2x3 matrix instead of a 3x3 matrix, but an NxN matrix has a few nice properties. One of the nice things is being simple to multiply with a vector. Position can be stored as vectors and we'd like to transform a vector by multiplying it with a transformation matrix. If you look at a vector as a single column vector, the 3x3 form of the matrix allow multiplication(see [matrix multiplication rules here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)).

In short:

1. You can store transformations in a matrix
2. You can apply these transformation to a vector using multiplication

Back to your issue, checking if a point is within a box with transformations applied, you can do this:

convert the test point's coordinate system to the box's transformed coordinate system by:

1. inverting the box's transformation matrix and
2. multiplying the point to the inverted transformation matrix.

This may be hard to comprehend at first, but one way to look at is imagining you rotate the whole 'world'(coordinate system) so your rotated box is straight (essentially rotating in the opposite direction, or inverting the transformation) then check if the point is in the box.

Luckily all these matrix operations don't need to be implemented from scratch: [PMatrix2D](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PMatrix2D.html) deals with this.

Here is a basic commented sketch explaining all the above:

```
Box box1,box2;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);

  box1 = new Box(200,100);
  box1.translate(75,100);
  box1.rotate(radians(30));
  box1.scale(1.1);

  box2 = new Box(100,200);
  box2.translate(275,150);
  box2.rotate(radians(-5));
  box2.scale(.95);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  box1.update(mouseX,mouseY);
  box2.update(mouseX,mouseY);
  box1.draw();
  box2.draw();
}

class Box{

  PMatrix2D coordinates = new PMatrix2D();//box coordinate system
  PMatrix2D reverseCoordinates = new PMatrix2D();//inverted coordinate system

  PVector reversedTestPoint = new PVector();//allocate reversed point as vector
  PVector testPoint = new PVector();//allocate regular point as vector


  float w,h;//box width and height
  boolean isHovered;

  Box(float w,float h){
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
  //whenever we update the regular coordinate system, we update the reversed one too
  void updateReverseCoordinates(){
    reverseCoordinates = coordinates.get();//clone the original coordinate system
    reverseCoordinates.invert();//simply invert it
  }

  void translate(float x,float y){
    coordinates.translate(x,y);  
    updateReverseCoordinates();
  }
  void rotate(float angle){
    coordinates.rotate(angle);  
    updateReverseCoordinates();
  }
  void scale(float s){
    coordinates.scale(s);
    updateReverseCoordinates();
  }
  boolean isOver(float x,float y){
    reversedTestPoint.set(0,0);//reset the reverse test point
    testPoint.set(x,y);//set the x,y coordinates we want to test
    //transform the passed x,y coordinates to the reversed coordinates using matrix multiplication
    reverseCoordinates.mult(testPoint,reversedTestPoint);
    //simply test the bounding box
    return ((reversedTestPoint.x >= 0 && reversedTestPoint.x <= w) && 
            (reversedTestPoint.y >= 0 && reversedTestPoint.y <= h));
  }

  void update(float x,float y){
    isHovered = isOver(x,y);
  }
  void draw(){
    if(isHovered) fill(127);
    else          fill(255);
    pushMatrix();
    applyMatrix(coordinates);
    rect(0,0,w,h);
    popMatrix();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [modelX()](https://www.processing.org/reference/modelX_.html) and [modelY()](https://www.processing.org/reference/modelY_.html) functions. Just pass in `mouseX` and `mouseY` (z is 0) to find the position of the mouse in rotated space. Similarly, pass in the position of your rectangles to find their rotated points.

Here's the example from the reference:

```
void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
  noFill();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  pushMatrix();
  // start at the middle of the screen
  translate(width/2, height/2, -200);     
  // some random rotation to make things interesting
  rotateY(1.0); //yrot);
  rotateZ(2.0); //zrot);
  // rotate in X a little more each frame
  rotateX(frameCount / 100.0);
  // offset from center
  translate(0, 150, 0);

  // draw a white box outline at (0, 0, 0)
  stroke(255);
  box(50);

  // the box was drawn at (0, 0, 0), store that location
  float x = modelX(0, 0, 0);
  float y = modelY(0, 0, 0);
  float z = modelZ(0, 0, 0);
  // clear out all the transformations
  popMatrix();

  // draw another box at the same (x, y, z) coordinate as the other
  pushMatrix();
  translate(x, y, z);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  box(50);
  popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to have this in 2D/default renderer

Comment: @Yaron Yes. This code is just an example. What happened when you tried it with the default renderer?